# Image flickering when inserted into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I noticed that when I do something like this (with jQuery, but I don't think it matters):

```
$("#myDiv").html("<img src='/image.png'/> this is my image.");
```

The browser displays the text first, and then the image is loaded, and shifts the text to the right which creates a horrible flickering effect.

The image doesn't appear to be cached by the browser. Any idea why ? How can I avoid this phenomena when loading images into the DOM ?

Comment: Flickering effect? Could you explain or demonstrate? I don't see flickering in my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nsbmW/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas  The flickering might appear at slow connections and large image files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`How can I avoid this phenomena when loading images into the DOM ?` there are two major methods (may be more :))

1) Set the actual size of the img  `<img with='20' height='20' src='...' />` or via CSS style.

2) Use image preload and insert your code only when image is loaded

```
var img = new Image(); 
$(img).load(function(){  
    $("#myDiv").append($(this))
               .append(document.createTextNode("this is my image.");
    // or your way, browser should take image from cache
    $("#myDiv").append("<img src='/image.png'/> this is my image.");     
 }).attr('src', '/image.png');
```

ps: there is a serious bag in SO engine - code formatting does not want to combine with numbered listing. So I removed the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you preload the image and make sure my dynamic HTML references the preloaded image ? Do I need to .append() it separately from the text ?

Comment: @Blacksad  `Do I need to .append() it separately from the text ` in general - no, I just was trying to make it.. stylish, while trying to turn on the formatting ))

Answer (score 1):

Preload the image before attaching it:

```
$("<img>", {
    load: function() {
        $("#myDiv").empty().append( this, "this is my image." );
    },
    src: "/image.png"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

preload your images like this

```
var images = [
'/path/to/some/image1.png',
'/path/to/some/image2.png'
 ];

$(images).each(function() {
var image = $('<img />').attr('src', this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Images may render a little slower that text,  even if cached. If you know the dimensions of the image **add `height` and `width` attributes to the image** and then it won't  jump around.